# Adding a parent node to one or more child nodes of an XML using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and i am trying to accomplish the follow case

I have an xml in the following format

```
<A>
    <B>..</B>
    <C>..</C>
     ..
    <Z>..</Z>
</A>
```

I am trying to add a new node  soon after  so that the final xml will get transformed to

```
<A>
   <aa>
      <B>..</B>
      <C>..</C>
       ..
       <X>...</X>
   </aa>
</A>
```

In order to achieve this i wrote the following xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="B">
    <aa>
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </aa>
</xsl:template>
```

By using this i get the following output

```
<A>
   <aa>
      <B>..</B>
   </aa>
      <C>..</C>
       ..
       <X>..</X>
</A>
```

I am not sure what kind of changes i need to make to the xslt to achieve the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wrap all the children of `A` in a *single* `aa` then you need to do that in a template matching `A`, not `B`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:copy><!-- copy the A -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /><!-- attributes, if any -->
      <aa><!-- insert the extra aa -->
        <xsl:apply-templates /><!-- process children -->
      </aa>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this may be a typo in the question, but for reference, here's how
       to rename Z to X.  If you don't need to do this, just leave this template
       out and let the identity template at the top handle it. -->
  <xsl:template match="Z">
    <X>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </X>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I got it. I understand what was the mistake with my approach.